# Objective-C Guid with Hyphens

Tags: objective-c, parsing, guid

All

I am looking to format a guid stored in an NSString with hyphens?  I would like to avoid substrings and use a formatter if possible

so
D21AB2C8-E61F-11E0-ADEE-20D04824019B

instead of 
D21AB2C8E61F11E0ADEE20D04824019B

The value is already in an NSString and I just need to add the hyphens, but I would rather not have to deal with parsing the String and inserting hyphens with substrings.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you are against parsing, but if you are so dead set against it then use an NSMutableString and insert your hyphens at the appropriate index.

```
NSMutableString * guid = [NSMutableString stringWithString: @"D21AB2C8E61F11E0ADEE20D04824019B"];
[guid insertString: @"-" atIndex: 8];
[guid insertString: @"-" atIndex: 13];
[guid insertString: @"-" atIndex: 18];
[guid insertString: @"-" atIndex: 23];

NSLog(@"GUID: %@", guid);
```

For the record, I think its better to use NSString's stringWithFormat and substrings, but to each his own.

Answer (score -1):

Use an NSCharacterSet

```
NSCharacterSet *set = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"-"];
NSString *newUUID = [myString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:set];
```